# I would like to know how to change an ISO date to UTC in python

Tags: python, date

I would like to know how to convert ISO date to UTC in python(2.6.6)

```
date_dob = getattr(model, value)
                 tz=pytz.UTC
                 date_dob =tz.localize(date_dob)
                 print(date_dob)
```

Here date_dob is mapped to DB property with value ISODate("1989-08-27T00:00:00.000Z").My requirement is to convert it into a UTC date time.

Output  1989-08-27 00:00:00+00:00 ,I believe its not a UTC value

Comment: `UTC` is a time zone, `ISO date` is a (date)time format

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import dateutil.parser
datestring = '1989-08-27T00:00:00.000Z'
yourdate = dateutil.parser.parse(datestring)
print(yourdate)


from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
date_str = '1989-08-27T00:00:00.000Z'
print(date_str)

datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
datetime_obj_utc = datetime_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone('UTC'))
print(datetime_obj_utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"))

datetime_obj_utc = datetime_obj.replace(tzinfo=timezone('US/Eastern'))
print(datetime_obj_utc.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z%z"))
```

Comment: No, I have a date object (date_dob ) and I want to change the time zone